# Sorting List<Entry<String, Integer>> using comparator

Tags: java

I'm trying to sort array `List<Entry<String, Integer>>` by integer. At start my code read a text file to string. Then is string split to words and save to string array and all words change to lower case. Then save words and theirs counts using hash map. Hash map is then transform to array list. Now I need to sort this list by integer using comparator. I tried it many ways but with no result. Here is my code and sorry for my english:

```
package test2;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        try {
            File file = new File("filee.txt");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder(150000);
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                build.append(line);
            }
            reader.close();

            String text = "";
            text = build.toString();
            String[] words;
            words = text.split("[,; .\\-\\\"]");

            String text0 = "";
            for (String str0 : words) {
                text0 = text0 + str0 + " ";
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                words[i] = words[i].toLowerCase();
            }

            Map<String, Integer> count = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                if (count.containsKey(words[i])) {
                    count.put(words[i], count.get(words[i]) + 1);
                } else {
                    count.put(words[i], 1);
                }
            }

            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : count.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
            }

            List<Entry<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Entry<String, Integer>>(count.entrySet());
            //Here I need to sort list using Collections.sort(list, Comparator)            


            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(list.get(i).getKey() + " : " + list.get(i).getValue());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please update your code sample with your best effort at a comparator and explain how it fails to meet your requirements. Currently it looks like you've not tried anything at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Collections.sort(count.entrySet(), new Comparator<Entry<String, Integer>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Entry<String, Integer> x, Entry<String, Integer> y) {
        return x.getValue() - y.getValue();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
@Override
    public int compare(Entry<String, Integer> arg0, Entry<String, Integer> arg1) {
        if (arg0 == null && arg1 != null){
            return -1;
        }else if (arg0 != null && arg1 == null){
            return 1;
        }else if (arg0 == null && arg1 == null){
            return 0;
        }

        if (arg0.getValue() == null && arg1.getValue() != null){
            return -1;
        }else if (arg0.getValue() != null && arg1.getValue() == null){
            return 1;
        }else if (arg0.getValue() == null && arg1.getValue() == null){
            return 0;
        }

        return arg0.getValue().compareTo(arg1.getValue());
    }
```